# Power Platform licenses, number of calls per 24 hours

Tags: office-365, licensing, power-platform

In regard to the number of calls per 24 hours for Power Platform licenses, then all those licenses have the same limit which is 6,000 calls per 24 hours?? : -

1. E1-E5 Enterprise Plans
2. Business Essentials
3. Business standard
4. F1 Plan

Second question, if we want to increase this limit (6,000 call per 24 hours), then what is the next license type we need to use?

Thanks

Comment: Check the licensing plans which are specific to Power Apps and Power Automate like per user and per app/flow plans.

Comment: @GaneshSanap Thans for the reply. i found some of them but they are really confusing... that why i asked this question.